# Android push notification using Sinch not working

Tags: android, push-notification, sinch

Hi so I've been following this tutorial by Sinch: https://www.sinch.com/learn/sinch-managed-push-calling-android/, and the problem is that the GcmBroadcastReceiver doesn't seem able to receive anything.

Before this I was able to have instant-messages between users with the chat activity open. Now I'm trying to get notifications when the chat activity is not opened. As far as I'm understanding, Sinch is supposed to take care of the push and all I need to do is to receive the push notification and do whatever I want with it. When I send message to one device using another, nothing happens as far as the push notification's concerned. Any help? Thank you very much!

My AndroidManifest related parts:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <permission android:name="com.myAppPackage.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myAppPackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    ...
    <!-- Chat Activities -->
        <service android:name=".Managers.MessageService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.myAppPackage"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

MessageService

```
...
public void startSinchClient(String username) {
        Log.d("SinchClient", "Started");
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        //sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);
        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        sinchClient.checkManifest();

        sinchClient.start();
    }
...
@Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
        Log.d("MessageService", "onClient success");
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
    }
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver

```
    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("onReceive", "called!");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

GcmIntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService implements ServiceConnection {

    private Intent mIntent;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        Log.d("GcmIntentService", "Created");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("GcmIntentService", "onHandleIntent");
        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushIntent(intent)) {
            mIntent = intent;
            connectToService();
        } else {
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
    }

    private void connectToService() {
        Log.d("GcmIntentService", "connectToService");
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, SinchClient.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        Log.d("GcmIntentService", "onServiceConnected");
        if (mIntent == null) {
            return;
        }if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushIntent(mIntent)) {
            SinchClient sinchService = (SinchClient) iBinder;
            if (sinchService != null) {
                //NotificationResult result = sinchService.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(mIntent);
                // handle result, e.g. show a notification or similar
                mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class), 0);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("New Message!");
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                mNotificationManager.notify(GlobalVars.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(mIntent);
        mIntent = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
    }
}
```

The tutorial I followed has things that had error, so instead of "SinchService", I'm using "SinchClient", which has the functions. Also Sinch doesn't have GitHub example for this particular tutorial :(
First time posting question:) Thanks again!

**Update:**
The receiver somehow works now, but the GcmIntentService is not responding to function `startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)))`

Comment: In the beginning of the learn article (its not a tutrial) it says  
"I’ll walk you through adding push to your Sinch app to app calling Android app. All of the code in this post can be found in the push sample app included in the Android SDK. Sinch uses GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to deliver push notifications."
I think you should download that and look at the code, trying to implement using only that info leaves quite alot out

Comment: Hey Alex, did you do anything special to get it to work? Because I'm having the same issue: I'm receiving nothing in the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @cjensen, I did follow their other tutorials to get the messaging app working, and the codes posted above are what I think that's relative to this problem. Thanks for the advice tho!

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel, hi, I think I took out the function sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection(); and added in sinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true); as the tutorial suggested, which got my GcmBroadcastReceiver working but it doesn't start the GcmIntentService. It also introduces another problem that causes my chat functionality to break(Can't listen for incoming messages)

Comment: @InnekeDeClippel, I'm currently just using the MessageClientListener originally in MessageActivity in my MainActivity, which listens for incoming messages and updates my chat user list. I also added notification in onIncomingMessage function, which notifies the user as long as the app is still in background. Even with the GcmBroadcastReceiver working, the response for a push is way slower than the way I mentioned above.

Comment: Alex, I got it to work. I didn't know the calling app needed managed push enabled as well. I was using the calling sample to make the test calls. When I tried to call from the push sample it worked. As to why your service isn't starting, I have no idea. Try starting from the sample code and modify it line by line for your needs. That usually does the trick for me.